# How to customize TinyMCE editor in Prstashop 1.7.7.6 : add buttons and use my own css

Tags: tinymce, prestashop

TinyMCE editor config installed in my Prestashop 1.7.7.6 is very simple/basic and I would like to change this config:
-add css style selector
-add font selector
-add my own css file (in order to get basic layout of my specific blocs)

I found this info https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/components/tinymce/ and modified the actionAdminControllerSetMedia hook in order to get my own config file (TinyMceConfig.js) loaded.

My file is effectively loaded and it's basic content is the following:

window.defaultTinyMceConfig = {
toolbar2: 'styleselect,|,formatselect,|,fontselect,|,fontsizeselect,',
}

Folder /var/cache has been deleted, but unfortunately, nothing changes in the editor (page or product).

What am I doing wrong here in order to customize TinyMCE in Prestashop?

Thank you in advance for your help.
Joe

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation on https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/components/tinymce/ this feature is available from version 1.7.8.